# I have 3-4 different API and the response is also different from other how to integrate as once

Tags: json, xml, api, integration

I have a bus ticket booking site and at preset i have 1 API now i got around 4 different API( and i will be getting another 20 API ) and each are different from other in response as well as technologies used like one API response is based on JSON and other API are based on XML so how to club or any process to use all as one API

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Adapter Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) which sounds like exact thing you need.

in this case you'll be calling your adapter classes that can get your json and format it according to your needs, then return the json in your desired format.